# Threejs: Visible light for spotlight

Tags: javascript, three.js, webgl, light

In my current project I need to make a visible spotlight, just like one which calls batman. I mean that cone of light, that you can see on a night sky.
I haven't any graphical or 3d experience and I just can't make light visible.
Would be nice if you can show me how do that or give couple advice.

Here is [codepen](http://codepen.io/Elfrey/pen/GDhIv) for experiments.
Thanks a lot.

P.S. I need visible whole cone, not just reflection from box.

Comment: Google for 'projective texture mapping'.

Comment: How does this three.js example look to you? http://threejs.org/examples/webgl_postprocessing_godrays.html Looks good in Safari; not so good in Chrome.

Comment: @AbstractAlgorithm thanks, going to read what it is.

Comment: @WestLangley I saw that example, but I hoped there is way to do that only with Three.js, without postprocessing or shaders. I'm not quite understand this technologies. But thanks.

Comment: Couldn't you simply make a cone out of transparent material?

Answer (score 2):

[JSFiddle Demo of batsignal-type spotlight](http://jsfiddle.net/Angrypickle/vrxmpvd9/48/)

Lights (and shadows) can be tricky for many reasons. They have many parameters and require much tweaking to look right. Just getting light to show up can be a little counter-intuitive which is why this line of code is your best friend:

```
light.shadowMapVisible = true;
```

Light objects are not visible. If you look at one, you won't see anything. If you want a sun in a sky that lights up your scene, you must create the light source **and** the sun object if you want something to see.

Getting light to show up usually means providing a surface upon which light can shine. In the example above, that surface is a sphere that surrounds us. In our example, we also build a yellow transparent cone to fake the beam of light. Try adding a texture to this cone to achieve greater realism. In real life, this cone would be visible as light from a spotlight reflecting off tiny particles in the air. In our 3d world, there are no particles to reflect off of unless we put them there, hence the cone. Good luck!

Tips:

- Remember that there are many kinds of lights. Some can cast shadows, some cannot. Some affect only certain materials.
- The renderer has a parameter called "maxLights" that defaults to 4.